# Perform $x_1^3+x_2^3+\cdots+x_n^3$ by basic symetric polynomials.

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

Perform $x_1^3+x_2^3+\cdots+x_n^3$ by basic symetric  polynomials $\sigma_1,...,\sigma_n$.

$\sigma_1=x_1+x_2+\cdots x_n\\ \sigma_2=\sum\limits_{i<j}x_i x_j\\
...\\ \sigma_n= x_1.x_2...x_n$

I tried with $n=3,n=2$ but i can solve in general case.

Comment: Start with $\sigma_1^3$ and see what's too much ...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities

Comment: As Jack says, this is exactly the content of Newton's Identities, which are described in answers to a very recent question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923546/how-to-get-determinant-of-a-in-terms-of-trak/923569#923569